# Azure DevOps Pipelines: Create a text file with the current build number

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a build and pipeline setup to build a solution and then upload the finished `.exe` file via ftp upload to my website. Everything works fine and I have it setup to make a new folder named `$Build.BuildNumber` (20181218.4 for example) with the `.exe` file in it so I can keep an archive of my finished builds.

Now I want to write the `BuildNumber` to a text file sitting somewhere in the root directory with a static path/url so my programms can read the file and get the newest build number and download the newest `.exe`.

How can I automate the process of creating such a text file with Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Comment: You can use a powerhsell task that will create this text file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create a text file using `powershell` task.

use following commands inside powershel task

```
New-Item pathtoFile\test.txt
Set-Content pathToFile\test.txt '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Comment: For me `Set-Content pathToFile\test.txt '$(Build.BuildNumber)'` worked.

Comment: fixed from $Build.BuildNumber to $(Build.BuildNumber)